# How to get likes count in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have 3 tables, Users, Posts, and Likes, the schemas of them just like

```
Users: 
id: ObjectId; nickname: string; ...

Posts:
id: ObjectId; title: string; authorId: ObjectId(relate to Users id); ...

Likes:
id: ObjectId; forId: ObjectId(relate to Posts id); ...
```

I'd to get the amount of all likes amount of a specific user, How can I do it? Can anyone help me, I'm using mongoose in Node.js.
(I get all posts of the user and loop them then calculate the likes amount currently, but I don't think it's a good solution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) `Posts` from `Users` in an aggregation pipeline. Then, repeat $lookup again `Likes` from the result. Finally, group by id of user and count the total number of likes.

Here is a [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/icnKXcof91d)